# ModRewrite if file exists having RewriteBase

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to use a folder to override any file in the file tree, keeping its "base" path.

Given that url: `https://example.com/base/path/filepath/file.png`

If I put a file in `/var/www/base/path/custom/overrides/filepath/file.png` it should rewrite to https://example.com/base/path/custom/overrides/filepath/file.png.

The .htaccess file is located in `/var/www/base/path/` folder.

This works, but gives a 404 if the override file doesn't exists:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /base/path/

    RewriteCond $1 !^custom/overrides
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ custom/overrides/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried this but it never rewrites:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /base/path/

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/custom/overrides/$1 -f
    RewriteCond $1 !^custom/overrides
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ custom/overrides/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: If your URL is `https://example.com/base/path/…`, then your document root should presumably point to `/var/www`? Then you’d currently be checking if `/var/www/custom/overrides/filepath/file.png` exists.

Comment: How can I account the RewriteBase ?

Comment: `RewriteBase` only affects how the _new_ URL is created, it does not change anything else. You simply need to specify the _correct_ path in your first RewriteCond here to check if the file actually exists.